# 418 header status, I'm a teapot

Tags: errors, server, post-status

I'm just backing up a clients via ftp site prior to working on it, when suddenly all urls are returning an error page with the header status being `418`.

A quick Google finds that this was created for an April Fools joke. Does any body have any idea why I would be getting this error?

Comment: Probably a plugin. Search in all files for that number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were right Toscho, it is a plugin called 'better WP-Security'

I did a search for '418' as suggested in the files I had backed up via ftp and found this:

```
$bwpsmemlimit = (int) ini_get( 'memory_limit' ) 

//if they're locked out or banned die
if ( ( $bwpsoptions['id_enabled'] == 1 ||$bwpsoptions['ll_enabled'] == 1 ) && $this->checklock( $current_user->user_login ) ) {

wp_clear_auth_cookie();
@header( 'HTTP/1.0 418 I\'m a teapot' );
@header( 'Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate' ); 
@header( 'Expires: Thu, 22 Jun 1978 00:28:00 GMT' );
die( __( 'error', $this->hook ) );

}
```

So I presume as because I was backing up the site via ftp, the security plugin must have locked me out due to so much traffic.  After 10 mins I could get back on the site again.